# How to open another page when I click on Image in MVC view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am rendering my data view as below:

```
@foreach (var movieDetails in Model)
{
    <div class="sameLine" onMouseOver="focusDiv(this)"  id="c4" onmousewheel="moveFocus(event)" onclick="playMovie(this)">
            <table border ="1" class="contentTable">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">
                <img src = @movieDetails.Thumbnail alt = @movieDetails.Thumbnail class="imgStyle"/>
                <div class="tvShowPanel">
                    @movieDetails.Title
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
}
```

I want the user to navigate from current page to another page when user click on image or the div containing the image , so I have handle this with javascript but not getting any prompt after that:

```
function playMovie(obj) {
    alert("Image Clicked");
}
```

Also please let me know how can I navigate to other page using playMovie ? Shall I use query string querystring with document.location or window.location?

If so , how do I pass the querystring from my view to the javascript?

current app is similar to Youtube, when you click on thumbnail it should navigate to another page and start playing the viedeo.

**Edit:**

MovieDetails class is as below:

```
public class MovieDetails
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        // public string URI { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string MovieURI { get; set; }
        // public List<Response> Response { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Does `movieDetails` have a property such as `URL`?

Comment: @AndreCalil, Yes movieDetails has a property URI. Updated the question with class for reference

Comment: You could add to the div another attribute, such as `navigateURI`. Then, at `playMovie`, you use `obj.navigateURI` to set the location of the page. If you need any additional info at this page, then you should pass it using the querystring. This will result on a `GET` call to one of the actions of the "play" view. Got it?

Comment: @AndreCalil, but my playMovie is not getting called while clicking on Image

Comment: For now code to fire playMovie function seems to be ok. Please open your browser console and let us know if you can see any errors there.

Comment: Add the same attribute and `onclick` function to the image. AFAIK, the `div`'s on click will only be called if you click directly on it (that is, not on the image).

Comment: @AndreCalil, Div does not have a attribute called navigateURI , If I try to access that navigateURI it always says undefined

Comment: @Simsons This attribute is not from the standard, it would be a custom attribute. I may retrieve it by calling `obj.getAttribute("navigateURI")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `<img>` element inside of `<a>` element, than you can navigate wherever you want by clicking on image.

```
@foreach (var movieDetails in Model)
{
    <div class="sameLine" onMouseOver="focusDiv(this)"  id="c4" onmousewheel="moveFocus(event)" onclick="playMovie(this)">
            <table border ="1" class="contentTable">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="@movieDetails.MovieURI">
                <img src = @movieDetails.Thumbnail alt = @movieDetails.Thumbnail class="imgStyle"/>
                <a/>
                <div class="tvShowPanel">
                    @movieDetails.Title
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
}
```